# Environment variables within docker images

Tags: docker, environment-variables, docker-compose

My goal is to use environment variables in the docker-compose.yml file that can be referenced inside the application itself like in `config/database.yml`

docker-compose.yml

```
...
environment:
  $DB_NAME: myapplication
  $DB_USER: appadmin
  $DB_PASS: secret
...
```

config/database.yml

```
...
database: $DB_NAME
db_user: $DB_USER
db:pass: $DB_PASS
...
```

But no matter how do I try to send the variables to my file, They don't get recognised. :(

Comment: Does the application parsing config/database.yml inside the container expand environment variables defined in that file?

Answer (score 0):

You're just trying to set the variables in the compose file?  You shouldn't need the "$" in front of them in that case:

```
environment:
  - DB_NAME=database
  - DB_USER=appadmin
  - DB_PASS=secret
```

You could use mappings too:

```
environment:
  DB_NAME: database
  DB_USER: appadmin
  DB_PASS: secret
```

When you reference them in the database config file, you can just use the variable name too, again, without the "$":

```
environment:
  DB_NAME
  DB_USER
  DB_PASS
```

You can check the [Compose Environment Options](https://docs.docker.com/compose/environment-variables/) documentation and the [Compose Environment reference](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#environment) for further information.

Hope that helps.

Comment: I'm trying to set the variable values in the compose file, but then trying to call them inside the docker images database config file. Gonna try soon the non-$ type of calling it, but honestly, I don't know if that could work. I mean isn't the whole point of $ to let the system know that is a variable and not a string?